# C GetTickCount (windows function) to Time (nanoseconds)

Tags: c, time, performancecounter

I'm testing one code provided from my colleague and I need to measure the time of execution of one routine than performs a context switch (of threads).

What's the best choice to measure the time? I know that is available High Resolution Timers like,

```
QueryPerformanceCounter
QueryPerformanceFrequency
```

but how can I translate using that timers to miliseconds or nanoseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the operation than i am executing is in order of 500 nanos, and the timers doens't have precision, what i made was,

i saved actual time with GetTickCount() - (Uses precision of ~ 12milis) and performs the execution of a route N_TIMES (Number of times than routine executed) than remains until i press something on console.

Calculate the time again, and make the difference dividing by N_TIMES, something like that:

int static counter;

> void routine()
>   {
>      // Operations here..
>      counter++;
>   }
>
> int main(){
>       start <- GetTickCount(); 
>       handle <- createThread(....., routine,...);
>       resumeThread(handle);
>
> ```
> getchar();
> ```
>
> WaitForSingleObject(handle, INFINITE);
>
> Elapsed = (GetTickCount() - start) * 1000000.0) / counter;
>      printf("Nanos: %d", elapsed);
>   }

:)

Answer (score 3):

```
LARGE_INTEGER lFreq, lStart;
LARGE_INTEGER lEnd;
double d;

QueryPerformanceFrequency(&lFreq);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&lStart);

/* do something ... */

QueryPerformanceCounter(&lEnd);
d = ((doublel)End.QuadPart - (doublel)lStart.QuadPart) / (doublel)lFreq.QuadPart;
```

d is time interval in seconds.

Comment: not work, is returning 1.0 when the execution methods remains aproches 10seconds

Comment: I'd guess that the reason it isn't working is that the above code performs an integer division and then casts it to a double. Try `d = ((double)(lEnd.QuadPart - lStart.QuadPart)) / lFreq.QuadPart);` instead and see if that helps.

Comment: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=291294 Actually, it is possible to use LowPart instead of QuadPart - 32 bit is quite enough.

Comment: Why are you casting to `doublel`? Is that a typo?